# Find the probability of specific combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Three of the digits $1, 2, 3$ and $4$ (in any order, repeats allowed) are used to write a number.  What is the probability that the number formed will be greater than $340$?

I am able to determine the number of possible combinations by: $4^3 = 64$, but I can't figure out where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

For a number to be bigger than $340$.

The first digit can be either $3$ or $4$.

If the first digit is $3$, the second digit must be $4$ and the last digit can be anything.

If the first digit is $4$, the last two digit can be anything.

Can you compute the probability now?

Answer (score 1):

In general suppose we have an alphabet of $n$ characters and a fixed permutation $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_k$ of them. We select a permutation of length $k$ of the alphabet randomly, what is the probability it is less than or equal to $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$?

This is given by the formula:

$$\frac{1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} f_i(n-i)^{\underline {k-i}}}{n^{\underline k}}$$

where $x^{\underline n}$ is the falling factorial and $f_i$ is the number of letters larger than $a_n$ in the alphabet that do not appear among $a_0,a_1,\dots, a_n$.

This can be calculated in time $\mathcal O (k\log(k))$